# How can I get GDB to work well on a program that uses the TRAP signal?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, signals

I am taking a large embedded codebase and making a linux executable (as a simulation). This software contains numerous direct accesses to memory-mapped register on FPGAs and for various reasons it isn't currently feasible to implement an abstrction layer. Instead, I am using a seg-fault handler plus processor single-step and a trap handler plus mapped memory in the "FPGA" region. The sequence is:

```
Segfault
Unprotect mapped memory.
Read simulation (i.e. insert values into the target area)
Set the target "trap" (single-step) flag
Set the "inSimulation" flag
Return
Trap
Clear the "inSimulation" flag
Write simulation (i.e. respond to written value)
Clear the target "trap" flag
Re-protect the mapped memory
Return
```

This works well and allows me to simulate everything I need to.

The problem is getting gdb to work well while debugging this code.

I set the GDB handling of segfault to be pass, nostop, noprint and this works well. The problem is with the TRAP signal, which gdb uses and processor single-stepping also uses. I handle it by setting a catchpoint which uses the "inSimulation" program (not gdb) flag to determine whether to forward the signal to the program under test.

Here is my current .gdbinit:

```
set pagination off

handle SIGSEGV nostop noprint

catch signal SIGTRAP
commands
if inSimulation
signal SIGTRAP
end
end
```

I would like GDB to "feel" exactly the same when debugging this simulation as when debugging any other program. Instead there is a LOT of noise from the catchpoint handling, continue has to be entered twice to take effect, next has to be entered a variable number of time, sometimes only once but other times 4 or even (maybe) 6.

So two questions:

Is there any way to stop catchpoint handling printing every time it's invoked?

Is there any way to improve the trap handling so that continues and steps don't require repeated entries?

Comment: Is GDB not using the trap signal for internals? Every breakpoint is a trap so using SIGTRAP as part of the normal application operation will never work with gdb. Maybe I am wrong

Comment: Is there any other signal you could use? SIGTRAP happens when a debugging condition is met.

Comment: @Klaus: It does work with gdb, it's just that it doesn't work as well as I'd like.

Comment: @Thomas: The SIGTRAP is generated by the processor in single-step mode. I don't have any say or choice in the matter.

Comment: @CPD I don't think there is a solution that will work for you. It's a hacky work-around, and those have a cost.